# get "Authorization has been denied for this request" when send post method with token

Tags: flutter, http, dart, post

I try to send post method with token but I get this error message "Authorization has been denied for this request"

and when I try that on postman work properly!!

may code:

```
Map<String,String> headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json','Accept': 'application/json','authorization':'Bearer $token'};
final msg = jsonEncode({ 'ID': widget._address.ID,
  'State': '15',
  'City': '168',
  'Plaque': plaqueController.text,
  'Unit': unitController.text,
  'Address': addressController.text,
  'Name': nameController.text,
  'Mobile': phoneController.text,
  'Tel': telController.text,
  'PostalCode': postalCodeController.text,
  'latlng': widget.location.latitude.toString()+','+widget.location.longitude.toString()
});

print("work function");
print(msg);
var url = "https://2sote.com/api/services/UserAddressEdit";
var body = await post(url,body: msg ,headers: headers);
```

Comment: did you try changing `authorization` with `Authorization`. The first letter is capital.

Comment: @FaiiziiAwan I tried but it did not answer

Comment: ok you can get the dart code from postman. check right corner you will find the code option above field section. click on it and select dart language, postman will create the call code for you. test with that code.

Comment: I think the problem because using `https`. Postman allows to bypass certificate check but in dart you need a trick (look for on stackoverflow). Try to call with `http` first (if remote host allows).